# Running an application that consists of JavaScript and Flash (swf and sf2)

Tags: javascript, flash

I want to run an open source project on my broswer.

First i downloaded the source code.
When i opened it, i saw a folder called JavaScript and inside thie folder, this what i see.

[image: contents_of_folder]

This is the first time that i get involved with a project that consists of Flash and JS, so how exactly do i run the app?

The readme.md file does not contain any information on how to run this.
I know the answer will be trivial, but i am in complete ignorance.

Comment: Lot's of good examples: https://demo.alphatab.net/index.html#general/simple.html

Comment: https://www.alphatab.net/

Comment: @RandyCasburn still cant make sense...

Comment: There is a script initialization and a Data Attribute Initialization?

Comment: If you cannot refer to the examples or understand the documentation, perhaps you should choose a different tool.